# Making server accessible on local network without opening ports

Tags: security, firewall

I'm responsible for operating the server for a small startup game developer based at my university for my placement year - mostly because I'm the only one of us with any network knowledge to speak of. Everything is working at the moment, but it relies on an incoming rule for port 8181 in the server firewall (as does Perforce, on 1666). Research of other stackoverflow questions indicates that's far from a secure option, but does not provide any alternatives. What should I be doing?

Additional information: Server is running WAMP with Mantis and MediaWiki on Windows Home Server 2011, workstations are mostly using Windows 8.1 and 10. Server connects to the internet via a Catalyst 2950 provided by the university. Five other workstations connect to that, with the remaining seven or so connected via the university's wireless.

Comment: how are you accessing your web server for your other system on the same lan, using public ip or private ip ?

Comment: Private IP in the 24-bit block.

Comment: Your comment below makes it sound like you want an alternative way of connecting to an application/service, other then opening a firewall port on the local server

Comment: I was indeed looking for that. The questions I was reading weren't differentiating between local server firewall rules and network firewall rules, and after discussion with the department technician (campus-renowned as the hardest man to find in the world) we've determined that the current solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: `it relies on an incoming rule for port 8181 in the server firewall (as does Perforce, on 1666). Research of other stackoverflow questions indicates that's far from a secure option` - Any firewall rule that allows inbound traffic is naturally a security risk, but how else would you expect clients to connect to the server on those ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no need to open ports or forward traffic on the network's firewall to the server for the purpose of accessing the server locally.

on the server itself it's required as you intend to connect to it.
clients should connect to the local adress of the server (in your local network) and not any public address.

if wireless network is passing through the catalyst you may add ACLs to allow only the wireless subnets to pass the firewall and be forwarded to the actual server.

Comment: Minus the ACLs this is what we're already doing; the firewall rule is on the server itself, and as we're on a university campus we have no control over the network itself.

Answer (score -2):

You just have to use private ip instead of public ip of the server, and make sure that other systems are on same LAN.